# Hibernate: delete of child wants to delete parent as well?

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

My application persists RECosts, each assigned to a Timerange. A timerange is assigned to a RealEstate.

When I create a Timerange and then immediately try to delete it again, I am getting a `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no action; FK_OY1P238K3TRS850XETM1STE4P table: RECOST`

I don't understand that, because at this stage there are no costs connected with that timerange.
**But according to the logs, hibernate tries to delete the RealEstate as well, which is not desired**. Why is that?

Log

```
22:31:50.428 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - delete from RETimerange where id=?
Hibernate: delete from RETimerange where id=?
22:31:50.429 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - delete from RealEstate where id=?
Hibernate: delete from RealEstate where id=?
```

Domain

```
@Entity
public class RETimerange {


    private int id;


    private Date datefrom;
    private Date dateto;
    private RealEstate realestate;
    private String comment;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Date getDatefrom() {
        return datefrom;
    }
    public void setDatefrom(Date datefrom) {
        this.datefrom = datefrom;
    }
    public Date getDateto() {
        return dateto;
    }
    public void setDateto(Date dateto) {
        this.dateto = dateto;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = RealEstate.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_realestate")
    public RealEstate getRealestate() {
        return realestate;
    }

    public void setRealestate(RealEstate realestate) {
        this.realestate = realestate;
    }
    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }
    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The association has

```
cascade = CascadeType.ALL
```

so, every operation, including `remove()`/`delete()`, is cascaded to the associated RealEstate.